# Execute two programs simultaneously

Tags: c++, concurrency, fork

I'm working to execute via Dec C++,

```
#include<windows.h>
int main()
{
       system("ping 8.8.8.8 -t");

}
```

and it successfully pings 8.8.8.8.

How would I ping two addresses simultaneously?

In other words, when I run the program, there will be two ping programs: instead of only pinging 8.8.8.8, they will ping 8.8.8.8 and 192.168.0.1 simultaneously.

Many thanks with your help,

Comment: Can't you just add another line with "192.168.0.1" instead of "8.8.8.8" ?

Comment: it only executed after ping to 8.8.8.8 is done. Im trying to do both 'ping 8.8.8.8' and 'ping 192.168.0.1' are execute at the same time once the program is launched.

Comment: Then you might want to search for multithreading (here maybe ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23728136/c-thread-asynchronous-running-simultaneously)

Comment: Hint: `fork` and then `system`.